# NSTextView inside NSTableView Blocks Scrolling

Tags: nstableview, nstextview, nsscrollview

I have an `NSTableView` and within each table row there is an `NSTextView`. I have disabled scrolling on the `NSTextView` in my storyboard. I can scroll my `NSTableView` just fine, but when my mouse cursor is over the top of the `NSTextView`, the scrolling stops. I assume this is because the `NSTextView` is intercepting the scroll behavior.

The arrow points to the `NSTextView`:

[image: Arrow points to the NSTextView]

Keep in mind that the `NSTextView` is in a subclassed `NSTableViewCell`.

```
class AnnouncementsVC: NSViewController, NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource {
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    //...
  }
  func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    //...
  }
  func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    //...
  }
}

class AnnouncementTableCell: NSTableCellView{
  @IBOutlet weak var message: NSTextView!
}
```

How do I make the `NSTextView` pass its scroll events up to its parent `NSTableView`? My guess is I will need `scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent)` but I'm unsure where it goes since I have two different classes at play here.

Comment: Do you need the `NSTextView` or can you use a multiline `NSTextField`?

Comment: I chose an `NSTextView` so that I could adjust the line height. I suppose I could use an `NSTextField` and use an attributed string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to subclass `NSScrollView` and implement `scrollWheel:` to conditionally (1) either consume scroll-events in your subclass-instance as needed, or (2) forward them to an enclosing scrollview, based on your instances' current scrollposition.

Here's a rather rudimentary implementation (Obj-C) that i've used in the past:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)e {


    if(self.enclosingScrollView) {

        NSSize
        contSize = self.contentSize,
        docSize = [self.documentView bounds].size,
        scrollSize = NSMakeSize(MAX(docSize.width  - contSize.width, 0.0f),
                                MAX(docSize.height - contSize.height,0.0f) );

        NSPoint
        scrollPos = self.documentVisibleRect.origin,
        normPos = NSMakePoint(scrollSize.width  ? scrollPos.x/scrollSize.width  : 0.0,
                              scrollSize.height ? scrollPos.y/scrollSize.height : 0.0 );

        if( ((NSView*)self.documentView).isFlipped ) normPos.y = 1.0 - normPos.y;

        if(   ( e.scrollingDeltaX>0.0f && normPos.x>0.0f) 
           || ( e.scrollingDeltaX<0.0f && normPos.x<1.0f)
           || ( e.scrollingDeltaY<0.0f && normPos.y>0.0f)
           || ( e.scrollingDeltaY>0.0f && normPos.y<1.0f) ) {

            [super scrollWheel:e];

        }
        else

            [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:e];

    }
    else 
        // Don't bother when not nested inside another NSScrollView
        [super scrollWheel:e];
}
```

It still leaves much to be desired, like handling the deltaX and deltaY components independantly, but perhaps it's sufficient for your case.

Comment: I found a Swift equivalent to that that I will post as an additional answer, but I'm essentially doing the same thing that you described. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Swift (4.2) version that works great:

```
class MyScrollClass: NSScrollView{
  override func scrollWheel(with event: NSEvent) {
    self.nextResponder?.scrollWheel(with: event)
  }
}
```

Just add that sub-class your `NSScrollView` and it should work.

Comment: in my case it was a WKWebView which was "stealing" the scroll, so I subclassed WKWebView and overrode scrollWheel() like this. thanks.